# Subclassing Cocoa means no subclass ivars in some cases?

Tags: objective-c

The question is generally coming from `self = [super init]`.

In case if I'm subclassing NSSomething and in my init's method `self = [super init]` returns object of different class, does it mean I am not able to have my very own ivars in my subclass, just because `self` will be pointing to different class?

Appreciate if you could bring some examples if my statement is wrong.

UPD: to make my question more precise.

```
@implementation Base
-(id) init
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
}
@end

@interface Child : Base
{
int myVeryOwnVar;
}
- (id) init;
- (void) dump;
@end
@implementation Child
- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
myVeryOwnVar = 5;

return self;
}
@end

Child *p = [[Child alloc] init];
[p dump];
```

This obviously crashed on sending message to `p` object, since it's now `NSNumber` and does not serve dump message. So I lost the control over myVeryOwnVar and in worse cases can have leaks and crashes.

Comment: Basically NSNumber is an exception to the rule, since it can in some cases be a pointer to a global instance (such as for 0 and probably 1 which makes a lot of sense when considering booleans). My answer still stands. Edit: never mind, I guess I misread the question just ever so slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, when `[super init]` is called, there's actually a hidden parameter there (`self`), which is the object set up by your classes `alloc`. The ivars are already there, but you pass the object that they're attached to (`self`) without doing so explicitly. `init` *does not* set up ivars, but rather initializes them with values.

`self` is already a valid object pointer when your `init` gets called and `[super init]` will in almost all cases return either that very same `self` or `nil`.

For a more detailed (and probably much more accurate) description see http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/what-does-it-mean-when-you-assign-super.html

Comment: I kind of missed the part where you specified the case of [super init] returning an instance of a different object. The right information to head towards would be "As with any class cluster, if you create a subclass of NSNumber, you have to override the primitive methods of its superclass, NSValue." but I'm afraid this is a bit beyond me to explain.

Answer (score 1):

The `self = [super init]` will not return an object of different class, although it can return an *instance* of the class that differs from the calling instance. 
However, it will **always** be of class NSSomething, or a subclass of NSSomething, and you are always able to have your own instance variables.

Comment: Class cluster init methods do not necessarily return instances of the superclass

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-397865

Comment: @JeremyP I edited the answer to indicate that it could be a subclass too